# How to add the custom top links in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento2

I want to know to add custom top links for CMS pages in magento 2 header.

I know how to add the custom top links in magento 1.x. What should I do in magento 2?

Answer (score 3):

Go to **app/design/frontend/Magento/YOUR_THEME\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml**

Try it this way and replace it with your identifier and link title:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="contact-us">
<arguments>
<argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</argument>
<argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact-us</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I tried above code but its not working. If I used `header.links` then its working fine. Can you please explain me it ?

Comment: @PrafulRajput : I will check this in latest setup and get back to you with thoughts.

Comment: @PrafulRajput is right.. this works in `header.links` but not in `top.links`

Answer (score 3):

here is a working solution:

```
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="your-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Your Link</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">Your Link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>        
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to **app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml** and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
 <referenceBlock name="header.links">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="faq">
 <arguments>
 <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">FAQ</argument>
 <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">faq</argument>
 </arguments>
 </block>
 </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Changes in Mage 2 should be placed in app/design/frontend/Theme. This also doesn't improve the answer previously given.

Comment: If you are developing custom separate module then its advisable to put all layout and templates under module directory. I have considered separate module while given this answer

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the theme .If it's Luma theme it supports header.links or if it's blank theme it supports top.links.

Answer (score 1):

**Open app/design/frontend/Magento/YOUR_THEME\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml and add below code under body tag.**

```html
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="my-account-link">
 <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
     <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact</argument>
     <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>
 </arguments>
 </block>
</referenceBlock>
```